# Getting User details from field "AssignedTo" in a custom List

Tags: 2007, list, development, splistitem, spquery

I have a Custom List, which have different fields, when I click on any user in field "assignedTo" it navigates me to another window and I can see user's Account, Name, email etc.

I am able to get all the items of the list and of that specific field but i dont know how can i get user's email out of it. am not sure if it's sharepoint thing or we made it custom. here's the code i made until now

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("www.local.com"))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList mySourceList = web.Lists["ListName"];

        SPQuery mySourceListQuery = new SPQuery();

        mySourceListQuery.Query =

            "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />" +
                     "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
            "</OrderBy>";

        SPListItemCollection mySourceItemColl = mySourceList.GetItems(mySourceListQuery);
                foreach (SPListItem mySourceListItem in mySourceItemColl)
            {
                if (!UserDetails.ContainsKey(mySourceListItem["AssignedTo"].ToString()))
                {
                    string name;
                    name = mySourceListItem["AssignedTo"].ToString();

                    name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf("#") + 1);


                    UserDetails.Add(name, mySourceListItem["Title"].ToString());
                }
            }

            foreach (SPUser user in web.Users)
            {
                if (UserDetails.ContainsKey(user.Name))
                    Console.WriteLine(user.Email);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SPFieldUser assignedto = mySourceList.Fields["AssignedTo"] as SPFieldUser;
...
...
foreach(SPListItem ...)
{
  if(!UserDetails...)
    {
        SPFieldUserValue assignedUser = assignedto.GetFieldValue(mySourceListItem["AssignedTo"].ToString());
        if(assignedUser != null)
           {
              string name = assignedUser.User.DisplayName;
              string loginName = assignedUser.User.LoginName;
              string email = assignedUser.User.Email;
           }

    }
}
```